# Scipy.optimize COBYLA constraint violation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I have an optimization problem with constraints, but the COBYLA solver doesn't seem to respect the constraints I specify.

My optimization problem:

```
cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda t: t},) # all variables must be positive
minimize(lambda t: -stateEst(dict(zip(self.edgeEvents.keys(),t)), (0.1,)*len(self.edgeEvents), constraints=cons, method='COBYLA')
```

and `stateEst` is defined as:

```
def stateEst(t):
    val = 0
    for edge,nextState in self.edgeEvents.iteritems():
        val += edge_probability(self,edge,ts) * estimates[nextState]
        val += node_probability(self, edge.head, ts, edge_list=[edge])* cost
    for node,nextState in self.nodeEvents.iteritems():
        val += node_probability(self, node, ts) * \
            (estimates[nextState] + cost*len([e for e in node.incoming if e in self.compEdges])
    return val
```

The probability functions are only defined for positive `t` values. The dictionary is necessary because the probabilities are calculated with respect to the 'named' t-values.

When I run this, I notice that COBYLA tries a value of -0.025 for one of the t-values. Why is the optimization not respecting the constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**COBYLA** is technically speaking an **infeasible method**, which means, that the **iterates might not be always feasible in regards to your constraints!** (it's only about the final convergence, where feasibility matters for these algorithms).

Using an objective-function which is not defined everywhere will be problematic. Maybe you are forced to switch to some **feasible method**.

Alternatively you could think about generalizing your objective, so that there are penalties introduced for negative t's. But this is problem-dependent and could introduce other problems as well (convergence; numeric-stability).

Try using [L-BFGS-B](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb), which is limited to bound-constraints, which is not a problem here (for your current problem!).

Answer (score 0):

For something this simple, just redefine your function to take any real value by taking np.exp(t) or even t**2, then take the log (or square root) of the solution.